# Circular border creating inner stroke

Tags: html, css

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g3QAZ/

The problem is that the white border around the image creates an inner black border that's just barely visible, but visible enough to be an annoyance.

Why is it creating that black inner border when the border is specifically white? Please help.

CSS:

```
body {
    background: black;
}

img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    border: 5px solid #fbfbfb;
}
```

Comment: Addition: it seems that when you change the background color of the body to any color, that inner border color will be the same color as the background. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the background of the image white to fix this:

```
img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    border: 5px solid #fbfbfb;
    background-color:#fbfbfb;
}
```

The reason this border gives a black inner border is because the image inherits the body's black background, and the border sometimes has pixels rounded off created a pixel between it and the image that will be filled with the image's background color.